# ProGuard - How to keep methods and obfuscate them at the same time?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to manually obfuscate my Android application (yes, I know, it's a pain) and for that I need to keep all the methods I implement yet also obfuscate them with ProGuard at the same time.

I have tried changing the config like this:

```
-keep class com.project.x.* {

}
```

But it kept all the class names and method names and still removed my unused code.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that you want two versions of each method: one with an obfuscated name, and one without?

Comment: I mean that I want to have all the methods obfuscated, but I don't want ProGuard to remove them if they are not used.

Answer (score 20):

As CommonsWare explained, it seems unlikely that you want to keep unused methods and yet have their names obfuscated, but ProGuard supports it as follows:

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class com.project.x.** {
    <methods>;
}
```

This forcibly keeps all methods (but not all classes) in the specified package (and its subpackages), but still allows their names to be obfuscated.

Comment: No it is not at all unlikely. Methods accessed via annotations at run time is one such example.

Comment: That's not very common in my experience, but possible indeed. The more precise configuration then is `-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * { @com.example.MyAnnotation <methods>; }`

Comment: It is also a valid case for proprietary AARs although the case is a bit different. Some library publishers want all their methods kept but the privates and internals be obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

Use keep option modifiers - see [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html)

I think you'd do something like this:

```
-keep,allowoptimization class com.project.x.* {

}
```

But to quote the documentation: "This modifier is only useful for achieving unusual requirements."

Have you tried to reverse enginner to see that this is something you need to do? My impression of keep is that it will preserve the class as an entry point to the app, but that it doesn't stop it optimising and obfuscating the methods of those classes internally.

Maybe all you want is `-keepnames` see that link above for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For some reason it throws an error that says that 'allowoptimization' was unexpected. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: I have reverse engineered my app, that's why I know I need to do this. The right syntax is -keep,allowoptimization.
My app is somehow messed up now when I compile it using ProGuard (even if I remove all the modifications), when I fix this I will be able to check if it worked. Thanks for all the help :-)

Comment: @EladCohen Ok, also have another thing for you to try which I put in answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I will let you know if it worked as soon as I fix my problems (apparently it also happens when I compile my app without ProGuard).

Comment: I don't know if it worked because my project has been messed up and I'm too lazy at the moment to fix it. I also think that I will test and implement all these obfuscations only when my app is complete. Thanks for the help.